# Convergency of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(kn)!}$, where $k > 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am confident that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(2n)!}\approx1.5923$$
converges. Other series such as 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(1.1n)!}\approx5.5690$$
appear to converge as well, and
my hypothesis is that the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(kn)!}, k > 1$$
converges.

I know that the $p$-series converges for $p>1$ due to the following relationship:
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}dx < \sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}<1+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^p}dx$$
However, I am not sure how to prove that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(kn)!}, k > 1$$
converges with the same method that is used to prove the convergency of the $p$-series.
Could you provide me some hints?

Comment: Have you tried ratio test?

Comment: What is $(1.1n)!$?

Comment: Note that $\frac{n!}{(kn)!}=\frac{1}{{kn\choose n}(kn-n)!}<\frac1{n!}$  for $k\ge 2$

Comment: @Hagen It is a coefficient. 11/10

Comment: @Larry: then what is $1.1!\ $ ?

Comment: @Anurag A:$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)!}{(kn+k)!}\right)}{\left(\frac{n!}{(kn)!}\right)}\right| = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left| \frac{(n+1)(kn)!}{(kn+k)!}\right|<1$$ Thank you for the hint, I think this will work when it can be proved that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left| \frac{(kn)!}{(kn+k)!}\right|>n+1$$
when $k>1$

Comment: $1.1!$ here is surely used to mean $\Gamma(1 + 1.1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log\Gamma(s+1)$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and
$$ \frac{n!}{(kn)!} = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(kn+1)}\leq \frac{1}{n^{(k-1)n}}.$$
Something similar but more accurate can be deduced from Stirling's inequality
$$ \left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^m\sqrt{2\pi m}\, e^{\frac{1}{12m+1}}\leq\Gamma(m+1) \leq \left(\frac{m}{e}\right)^m\sqrt{2\pi m}\, e^{\frac{1}{12m}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**By elementary means:**

For any natural $m$,

$$kn-n\ge m$$ for sufficiently large $n$, so that $$\dfrac{(kn)!}{n!}\ge\lfloor kn\rfloor\lfloor kn-1\rfloor\cdots(n+1)>n^m.$$

Hence the series converges.

Comment: I like the direction your answer is taking, but could you clarify how $m$ appears in the product you have written out? Maybe with \underbrace?

Comment: @AOrtiz: the number of factors in the product is the difference between the largest and the smallest, $\lfloor kn\rfloor-n$.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the clarification! +1

Answer (score 2):

Since $k > 1$, write $k > 1 + \frac{1}{N}$ for some $N$ sufficiently large. Then if $n > 2N$, we have $$kn > \big(1+\frac{1}{N}\big)n = n + \frac{n}{N} > n+2.$$
Thus for such $N$, we have
$$\sum_{n> 2N} \frac{n!}{(kn)!} \le \sum_{n>2N} \frac{n!}{(n+2)!} =\sum_{n>2N}\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)} \le \sum_{n>2N}\frac{1}{n^2},$$ which converges by the $p$-test.